# data-dojo-attach-point Values not resolving in related Custom Widget Class

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've defined the following template for my custom widget (this is just an example, it doesn't necessarily "work" yet)

template "**VehicleControl**"

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="carSelect" data-dojo-type="srcore.widget.input.Select" title="Select Car" required="true"></div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="wheelsSelect" data-dojo-type="srcore.widget.input.Select" title="Select Wheels" required="true"></div>
</div>
```

and here's my related **custom widget class**, showing you the first part up till where I try to reference the attach point "carSelect"

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/on",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "./_InputWidgetMixin",
    "../secure/_SecureWidgetMixin",
    "sc/widget/input/Select" // our extension of the base digit seelct
],
    function (declare, array, lang, on, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetBase, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _InputWidgetMixin, _SecureWidgetMixin)
    {
        return declare("srcore.widget.input.VehicleControl", [_WidgetBase, _InputWidgetMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _SecureWidgetMixin],{

        _templateString: dojo.cache("srcore", "widget/templates/VehicleControl.html"),

        _carDropdown: null

        constructor: function() {
            this._parentWidgetNode = this.domNode;
            this._carDropdown =  this.carSelect;

...
```

The problem is, when I'm in WebStorm (JetBrains Editor), it's showing that `this.carSelect` is not resolving.  I do not know what I am missing in this code and why this is not resolving when I have included _WidgetBase, _InputWidgetMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin to inherit from.

Isn't that enough?  Shouldn't this be resolving by now?

also how do I format code in Nabble?  What code tags do I need to surround code I paste in here with?

Answer (score 2):

Widgets in the template do not get instantiated until the `buildRendering` part of the [Widget lifecycle](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetBase.html#id5).

You probably want to wait until the `postCreate` part of the lifecycle to start working with the widgets in the template:

```
define([...], function(...){
  return declare("srcore.widget.input.VehicleControl", [_WidgetBase, _InputWidgetMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, _SecureWidgetMixin],{

    _templateString: dojo.cache("srcore", "widget/templates/VehicleControl.html"),

    _carDropdown: null

    postCreate: function(){
      //make sure any parent widget's postCreate functions get called.
      this.inherited(arguments);

      //can now work with this.domNode and this.carSelect
    }

});
```

I'm also not sure why you are simply copying references to this.domNode and this.carSelect to other variables-- you should always be able to get references to those properties from the widget itself.

Comment: I think it's not resolving at compile time but will still work at runtime.

Comment: the this.carSelect is simply using the attach point to reference that dom node from my widget control.  http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/understanding_widget/

Comment: As Buffalo mentioned, any dom access should be done in the postCreate. Also like he said: "this._parentWidgetNode = this.domNode;" is not useful as you can access this.domNode anywhere in the widget.

Comment: I don't know man, we don't always use postcxreate and those that don't have been working just fine....

Comment: I can't speak to other usages, but anything that uses _TemplatedMixin to build the widget doesn't assign domNode until the end of the `buildRendering` phase (https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_TemplatedMixin.js)